# Node in Terminal Mac. 3 dots keep showing up as in '...'

Tags: node.js, macos, terminal

I am using node.js in Terminal on my Mac and 3 dots keep showing up as in: '...' The code is correct (no mistakes) there is nowhere I can go from here. Every time I press enter the 3 dots are there. The only way to escape is to restart Terminal. Can anyone help?

Comment: can u paste your code.

Comment: That means that you created but didn't complete a scope. You're missing a `}`, `)`, or `]` somewhere, so it's impossible to say without seeing code

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! When you joined, you were asked to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Before you ask your next question, please take the tour, read [How to Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and read [how to provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Then you can apply what you've learned by editing this question. Good luck!

Comment: Hi, I only just noticed your messages. Thank you for that. You are right in what you say about the reason it does it, the scope wasn't completed, but on a couple of occasions, it did it when the scope was completed so I'm not sure why that happened. Also, I will take the tour so I ask questions in the proper format.

Answer (score 0):

All I have to do is use CTRL C and it goes back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

Although CTRL C returns node to working order it cancels out everything previously coded. Is there a way, other than CTRL C, to cancel just the block that caused the problem?